# How to skip the failed row in ADO?

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-c++, ado

I am using ADO to access SQL Server database.

I define recordset blow:

```
_RecordsetPtr m_pRecordset;
```

After opening the recordset for a table, I try to start a loop:

```
while (!m_pRecordset->ADOEOF)
{
    …(do some tasks) …
    m_pRecordset->MoveNext();
}
```

However, in the row 44, when invoking m_pRecordset->MoveNext(), it will raise an exception indicating the value in the next row(row 45) is invalid. Then the exception will abort the whole loop. How can I skip the row with the invalid value and continue with the row after the invalid row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since `MoveNext` will throw an exception, you can start by embedding that call in a `try`/`catch` block.  When you catch an exception, you want to ignore that record and move on to the next one.  That can be handled in several ways.

One way is to have a flag to indicate if you have a valid row, then check that before doing all the "do some tasks" stuff.

Another way is to put the `try`/`catch` block within a loop that you break out of if you successfully read a row, and stay in if you failed.  This way can be tricky, since you also have to check for EOF before looping.